# Bootstrap 4 : align content inside cards deck

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have a deck of cards in my Bootstrap 4 page. I want to align these button to have a nicer look. How can we do that?

Here is an image:
[image: Screenshot]

And here is the demo : http://7freres.com/new

The table dosen't seem to works, as they are separated.

Thanls

Comment: _"...have a nicer look"_ is very vague. What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SexyTurnip I want the button to be aligned, on mobile and desktop.

Comment: Greetings from the future. Since an external link was used to reference  the original code, and the link is now 404, this question is useless. This is why code should always be posted in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make all the `card-text` elements to have the same height.
One way to do it can be through javascript. Write a function like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    adjustCardTextHeights();
});

function adjustCardTextHeights() {
    var heights = $(".card-text").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".card-text").height(maxHeight);
}
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    adjustCardTextHeights();
});

function adjustCardTextHeights() {
    var heights = $(".card-text").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".card-text").height(maxHeight);
}
```

This gets you:
[image]

Comment: I have added `window.onload = function() {
        function adjustCardTextHeights() {
            var heights = $(".card-text").map(function() {
                return $(this).height();
            }).get();
            maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
            $(".card-text").height(maxHeight);
        };
    };` and it'S dosent work. How do you have done this?

Comment: Then you should also call the function with `adjustCardTextHeights ()` in onload. Or you can just get rid of the function and just have the content in the onload function.

Answer (score 0):

You could set `position: absolute; bottom: 20px;` for the buttons and add an extra `padding-bottom: 50px;` to the `card-block`